# Getting access token issue with twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am getting the following error. Any help ?

```
09-25 20:44:58.934: WARN/System.err(3741): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException: Request token or token secret not set in server reply. The service provider you use is probably buggy.
09-25 20:44:58.934: WARN/System.err(3741):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:202)
09-25 20:44:58.934: WARN/System.err(3741):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveAccessToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:97)
09-25 20:44:58.934: WARN/System.err(3741):     at corp.encameo.app.TwitterApp$3.run(TwitterApp.java:145)
09-25 20:44:58.981: ERROR/TWITTER(3741): Error getting access token
```

At line 145 of TwitterApp.java

```
new Thread() {
      @Override
        public void run() {
            int what = 1;

            try {
                (line 145) mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveAccessToken(mHttpOauthConsumer,
                    verifier);

                mAccessToken = new AccessToken(
                    mHttpOauthConsumer.getToken(),
                    mHttpOauthConsumer.getTokenSecret());

                configureToken();

                User user = mTwitter.verifyCredentials();

                mSession.storeAccessToken(mAccessToken, user.getName());

                what = 0;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 2, 0));
        }
    }.start();
```

using the following libraries:

`signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar` , 
`signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar` , 
`signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar` , 
`twitter4j-core-2.1.6.jar` .

Comment: What's going on at `TwitterApp.java:145` ?

Comment: @Adel: added whats there at line 145.